# Convert character vector to data.frame with max row limit?

Tags: r

Is it possible to convert a character vector into a data.frame with a max row length of 5, and the character vector just fills the rows up, making as many new columns as necessary to lay all the data out to cater towards the 5 max row limit?

Here's an example of a vector I wanna work with

```
> Animals
 [1] "Dogs"         "Cats"         "Birds"        "Fish"         "Rabbits"      "Horses"       "Cows"         "Sheep"        "Leech"        "Cheetah"     
[11] "Chicken"      "Fox"          "Monkey"       "Stingray"     "Pug"          "Parrot"       "Lion"         "Donkey"       "Bat"          "Crab"        
[21] "Dolphin"      "Killer Whale" "Peacock"      "Turkey"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could calculate number of rows based on number of columns and add data in a matrix which can be changed to dataframe.

```
nr <- 5
nc <- ceiling(length(Animals)/nr)
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(Animals[1:(nr*nc)], ncol = nc))
```

Comment: Oh cool that definitely did most of what I was looking for. Forgot to mention in the post, I was also hoping to be able to access each list of columns with something like `Animals[2]`, `Animals[5]`. So I can send columns where I need. I found when trying to run this type of statement with a matrix it only returns one leading character? What would be a good work around for this?

Comment: You can use `data[1]` , `data[2]` etc to access each individual columns in the dataframe.

Comment: Just saw the update sweet. Btw what's the function  "ncol = nc" ? Number of columns = the ceiling set?

Comment: Yes, check `?matrix` it is number of columns which is calculated using `nc <- ceiling(length(Animals)/nr)`